# Source control tool for Salesforce development

Tags: administration, code, tools

I am looking for a source control tool like Github which can do the following for us.

1. Provide a cloud based source control repository like subversion, etc.
2. Provide web based view to track changes.
3. Has automatic builds so that we can do deployments.
4. Project management interface for agile projects.

Can you guys recommend some tools which you use now which does all of this?

Thanks,
Buyan

Answer (score 6):

At LevelEleven, we use Github exclusively. One of the main reasons is the [issues module](https://github.com/blog/831-issues-2-0-the-next-generation). Now that you can inline images into an issue, it's an incredible bug/issue tracker for QA. We also use it to track our new features. Grouping features and issues into milestones essentially serves as an agile tool for us. Also, Github allows you to tag issues in your commit messages so that the commits show up when you pull up an issue. Not sure if BitBucket does this but it's one of my favorite features.

We are also setting up a Jenkins server on AWS so we can do continuous integration. We are setting up a [webhook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) to kick of the build within Jenkins. This way, whenever we push to master, Jenkins will receive the hook and deploy to our staging and other test orgs.

You might also like [this post by Josh Birk](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html) on using Jenkins for Force.com development.

Comment: O Hara  Thanks very much for your quick response. I would review both the tools and let you know what i find and go with. I know there is a bit of time to setup automated builds with jenkins. Do you guys know off hand does Github or Bitbucket provide it as a service to do this?

Comment: @DancinLlama  Thanks very much for your quick response. I would review both the tools and let you know what i find and go with. I know there is a bit of time to setup automated builds with jenkins. Do you guys know off hand does Github or Bitbucket provide it as a service to do this?

Comment: For the Jenkins CI piece, Github and BitBucket don't provide this. However, Jenkins is really easy to set up. It's just a java app that you download as a .war file and run. You could easily spin up an small linux instance on EC2 and with a couple of configurations, have it going pretty quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Im using bitbucket (http://www.bitbucket.org) for my current project.  Works pretty well for most of the above.  Bitbucket vs Github are very similar, the first is great for small teams + private repositories while the latter is great for several users / public projects.

Bitbucket also has the web based views, bug tracking and wikis built in.  I don't think it has tasks (I could be wrong), but wouldnt be too difficult to add on.

For automatic builds, I wrote an ant script that pulls the latest code from the master and pushes it to a Salesforce org using a combination of an ant exec call and the salesforce migration toolkit, so that part is very doable.  It also has Jenkins (a CI tool) and other plugins as well.

Comment: I can only second this, we use Bitbucket ourselfs with our entire team, though mostly we work on projects with max 2 people working at the same time, and for now everything runs very smoothly

Comment: Bitbucket now has pipelines for continuous delivery. And is easily integrated with JIRA (Issues) and Confluence (wiki) wich are atlasssian tools

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but RedHat published their internal Force.com backup and change tracking tool, [StratoSource](https://github.com/StratoSource/StratoSource/wiki), on github.  Core features include:

- Automatically detecting changes in environments (i.e. config changes) and committing to git repo
- Analyzing changes intelligently (knowledgeable about the structure of SFDC metadata)
- Group changes around development stories to simplify deployents

Their [2011](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4C2Jy-74sU) and [2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbCA-DX5k38) Dreamforce presentations give a good idea of how it works.  Seems like it would involve some heavy setup.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/03/setting-up-jenkins-for-force-com-continuous-integration.html

Jenkins can also be used along with the Tomcat or a server space over amazon for source control.